# data-icon is not showing properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am newbie to jquery mobile. I am executing the attached code.I have anchor tags whose role is button and attached data-icon as arrow-r but it is not showing properly as I expected.please help.
Arrow icon is showing like this
[image: Arrow icon is showing like this]

but I expected to show like this
I expected to show like this

[image]

am I missing CDN?Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
 

   <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            
            <title>Hello World</title>
            <style type="text/css">
             .custom-btn{
                width:200px !important;;
                height: 50px !important;;
             }
             #btn1{
                height: 8px;
             }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
     <div id="home" data-role="page">
          <div data-role="header">
            <h1 class="head">home</h1>
            <a href="blog.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home" style="height:8px;width:50px">Blog</a>
            <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" style="height:8px;width:50px">Home</a>
          </div>
       <p>Welcome to the view source app</p>
       <!-- <div data-role="controlgroup"> -->
       <a href="blog.html" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r">Blog</a>
       <a href="#videos" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r">Videos</a>
    <a href="#Photos" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r">Photos</a>
    <a href="#Tweets" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r">Tweets</a><!-- 
    </div> --> 
     </div>
     <div  data-role="page" id="videos" data-title="View Source:Videos">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Videos</h1>
      <a href="#home" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" style="height:8px;width:50px">Videos</a>
    </div>
    <p>Videos page</p>
    <a href="blog.html" data-transition="pop">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Photos" data-role="page" data-title="View Source:Photos">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Photos</h1>
     <a href="#home" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" style="height:8px;width:75px">Photos</a>
    </div>
    <p>Photos page</p>
    <a href="blog.html" data-transition="pop">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div id="Tweets" data-role="page" data-title="View Source:Blog">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Tweets</h1>
      <a href="#home" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" style="height:8px;width:50px">Home</a>
    </div>
    <p>Tweets</p>
    <a href="blog.html" data-transition="pop">Home</a>
    </div> 
    <!-- Start of first page: #one -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your data-icon attribute to `carat-r`:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="carat-r" style="height:8px;width:50px">Home</a>
```

Please take a look to the icon list: https://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/

And you have linked twice the jQuery Mobile JS library and the stylesheet. Try using only one of each at the same time.